# doxygen C pointer to function argument documentation

Tags: c, function-pointers, doxygen

I have a C function that takes pointer to a function as an argument. This function argument is supposed to be supplied by a library user so it is not implemented in source files.

```
/** @brief Map function.
 *
 * Apply function to each node of list.
 *
 * @relates list
 * @param[in] self list handle.
 * @param[in] func function to apply to list nodes.
 * @param[in] data user data passed to function.
 */
void map(struct list *self,
         void (*func) (void *node, void *data),
         void *data);
```

I'm writing documentation to it using [doxygen](http://doxygen.nl/) and I'm not sure how to document arguments and return values of the pointer to a function argument `func`.
It's possible to do it inside `@param func` field but it seems awkward.

What is the best way to document arguments and return values of the pointer to the function `func` using doxygen?
Is it possible to create a nested function documentation for `func` inside `map` or to create a dummy function documentation that can be referenced?

Comment: Can't you typedef the function pointer type and document that? see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30803441 for an example.

Comment: @Hasturkun I have a number of such functions and it seems a bit extreme to do so. `typedef` just for documentation sake...

Comment: I think it can improve readability somewhat (e.g. `void (*func) (void *node, void *data)` vs `mapFn` as an argument or something similar, with a hopefully descriptive type name). Also makes things less obscure if you ever find yourself with a pointer to a function accepting a pointer to a function, etc.

Comment: @Hasturkun that's a good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Hasturkun pointed out, the solution is to use a typedef.

See for example how this is done in MySQL, which uses a lot of function pointers in structures:

Typedef definition of `start_mutex_wait_v1_t`:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/include/mysql/components/services/psi_mutex_bits.h#L179

```
/**
  Record a mutex instrumentation wait start event.
  @param state data storage for the locker
  @param mutex the instrumented mutex to lock
  @param op the operation to perform
  @param src_file the source file name
  @param src_line the source line number
  @return a mutex locker, or NULL
*/
typedef struct PSI_mutex_locker *(*start_mutex_wait_v1_t)(
    struct PSI_mutex_locker_state_v1 *state, struct PSI_mutex *mutex,
enum PSI_mutex_operation op, const char *src_file, unsigned int src_line);
```

Use of the typedef in struct `s_mysql_psi_mutex_v1`:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/include/mysql/components/services/psi_mutex_service.h#L37

```
start_mutex_wait_v1_t start_mutex_wait;
```

Resulting doxygen doc:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/structs__mysql__psi__mutex__v1.html